# Is there any way to write a dimensional text on the image in php?

Tags: php, image

Is there any way to write a dimensional text on the image exactly like **From** text as attached photo in `PHP`?

[image]

What I tried before:

```
$sourceImage = "photo.jpg";
$destinationImage = "new-photo.jpg";

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImage);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 50, 50, 50);

$text = "A sample text";
$font = "font.ttf";
$fontSize = 18;
$rotation = 25;
$x = 370;
$y = 400;
$quality = 90;

imagettftext($image, $fontSize, $rotation, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
imagejpeg($image, $destinationImage, $quality);
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but imagemagick should be able to do that.

Comment: what does your code show ?

Comment: @user1281385 It shows like attached photo. "A sample text"

Comment: oh i see - i mis understood http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540001/perspective-transformation-with-gd